# Raphael JS background change

Tags: raphael

would like to know why the color of the rectangle change when I'm on the text.
I would like the background color is always the same as I am in the rectangle.

http://jsfiddle.net/yVzXF/11/

```
paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 250);

rectangle2 = paper.rect(130, 75, 140,40,15);
texte = paper.text(200, 90, "Tarification et souscription\nweb")

rectangle2.mouseover(function(){
    this.animate({
    fill : "#aaa"
    });
    });

rectangle2.mouseout(function(){
    this.animate({
    fill : "#F90"
    });
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is a separate element, so it has separate event handlers. If you add the event handlers for the text as well, you'll get the result *I think* you're looking for:

```
texte.mouseover(function(){
    rectangle2.animate({
        fill : "#aaa"
    });
});

texte.mouseout(function(){
    rectangle2.animate({
        fill : "#F90"
    });
});
```

Here's your [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVzXF/12/)